# Can we say anything interesting about group actions on a common set from isomorphic groups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, group-actions

This is a general question I have and not related to any specific problem. Suppose we have two groups $G, H$ with respective actions $A: G \times X \rightarrow X$ and $B: H \times X \rightarrow X$ on some set $X$. If $G \cong H$, does this imply any interesting relations between $A$ and $B$? I know that $A$ and $B$ need not be related with regards to primitivity, blocks etc.

My intuition is no, since $A$ could just be the trivial group action. If this is the case, does adding any constraints (say faithfulness) give us more interesting results? Thanks.

Comment: Isomorphic groups are structurally equivalent, and so they hare essentially indistinguishable from the viewpoint of group theory. In particular, the (equivalence classes of) actions of $G$ on sets $X$ must correspond to those of $H$.

Comment: @DerekHolt But can we say anything about two _individual_ actions $A$ and $B$?

Comment: I think @DerekHolt's point was that we might as well just ask about two different actions by the same group on the same set.

Comment: In general a group can have lots of different actions on the same $X$, even with restrictions like transitivity and primitivity. It would be less usual to have two inequivalent $2$-transitive actions on the same set.

Comment: You are essentially asking if there is anything interesting to say about two distinct actions of the same group on the same set. The answer is "not in general."